# Why does Rails insert a newline and 6 tab characters when using link_to?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have the following code:

```
<%== "From:<br>" %>
<% if flag %>    
  <%= link_to user.full_name, user_path(:user => { :user_id => user_id }) %>
<% else %>
.
.
.
```

This works fine, except it outputs a newline and 6 tabs before the link.

```
From:<br>
                <a href="/user?...
```

This turns into 1 space on the HTML page, breaking the left alignment of the text.

```
To:
 Joe
Brown
```

Why is it outputting a newline and 6 tabs? Is there a way to suprress this behavior? Is there a CSS solution to create a `<span>` that will not display tabs as whitespace on the HTML page?

Working in rails 3.07.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in CSS. I think this is a little more robust and allows more flexibility to make Rails code more readable.

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE 8 (on Windows).

```
user_name a {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
}
```

By the way, the HTML code is in a td.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code this way:

```
<%= "From:<br>#{link_to(user.full_name, user_path(:user => { :user_id => user_id })) if flag}" %>
```